# Finding Banned Words On A Page And Not Within Other Words

Tags: php, regex, curl

I am trying to add a banned words filter onto a web proxy.
I am NOT searching for banned words within other words on a page but searching for banned words within a loaded page.
I am not actually looking for banned words within other words but within the page (meta tags, content).

And so, if I am looking for the word "cock", then the word "cockerel" should not trigger the filter.

I just tested this code and, yes, as expected the code works but as you can guess there is a lot of cpu power cycling through. One moment the page loads, the other moment it goes grey and shows signs that the page is taking too long to load. And all this on localhost. Now, I can imagine what my webhost would do! 
So now, we will have to come-up with a better solution. Any ideas ?
How-about we do not get the script to check on the loaded page for all the banned words ? How-about we get the script to halt as soon as 1 banned word is found and an echo has been made which banned word has been found and where on the page ? (meta tags, body content, etc.).
Any code suggestions ?

Here is what I got so far:

```
<?php

/*
ERROR HANDLING
*/

// 1). $curl is going to be data type curl resource.
$curl = curl_init();

// 2). Set cURL options.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.buzzfeed.com/mjs538/the-68-
words-you-cant-say-on-tv?utm_term=.xlN0R1Go89#.pbdl8dYm3X');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

// 3). Run cURL (execute http request).
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$response = curl_getinfo( $curl );

if( $response['http_code'] == '200' )
    {
        //Set banned words.
        $banned_words = array("Prick","Dick","***");

        //Separate each words found on the cURL fetched page.
        $word = explode(" ", $result);

       //var_dump($word);

       for($i = 0; $i <= count($word); $i++)
       {
           foreach ($banned_words as $ban) 
           {
              if (strtolower($word[$i]) == strtolower($ban))
              {
                  echo "word: $word[$i]<br />";
                  echo "Match: $ban<br>";
           }
          else
           {
                 echo "word: $word[$i]<br />";
                 echo "No Match: $ban<br>";  
            }
         }
      }
   }  

// 4). Close cURL resource.
curl_close($curl);
```

I am told to do it like this:

**Load the page into a string.
Use preg_match with "word boundaries" on the loaded string and loop through your banned words.**

Q1, How do I load the page into a string ?
But, I have no clue how to start on this. And so, any sample code would be appreciated by all newbies including me.
Any code samples welcome.

UPDATE:
I updated my code inserting miknik's codes. It was working fine until I added this line before the cURL:
$banned_words = array("Prick","Dick","***");

Here's the update:

```
<?php

/*
ERROR HANDLING
*/

// 1). Set banned words.
$banned_words = array("Prick","Dick","***");

// 2). $curl is going to be data type curl resource.
$curl = curl_init();

// 3). Set cURL options.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.buzzfeed.com/mjs538/the-68-
words-
you-cant-say-on-tv?utm_term=.xlN0R1Go89#.pbdl8dYm3X');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

// 4). Run cURL (execute http request).
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$response = curl_getinfo( $curl );

if($response['http_code'] == '200' )
     {
          $regex = '/\b';      // The beginning of the regex string syntax
          $regex .= implode('\b|\b', $banned_words);      // joins all the 
          banned words to the string with correct regex syntax
          $regex .= '\b/i';    // Adds ending to regex syntax. Final i makes 
          it case insensitive
          $substitute = '****';
          $cleanresult = preg_replace($regex, $substitute, $result);
          echo $cleanresult;
     }

  curl_close($curl);

  ?>
```

Comment: q1, you already have the page in the `$result` string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the page content as a string already, it's in `$result`

`preg_match` will work but what do you then want to do when you find a match? `preg_replace` is more appropriate if you want to filter the banned words.

There is no need to explode the string into individual words, you are just adding a lot of cpu overhead by doing so. Process the `$result` variable as is.

So first off construct a regex string from your array of banned words. A basic syntax for matching each word is `\bXXXX\b` where XXXX is your banned word. `\b` at each end means that it must be at a word boundary, so `\bcock\b` would match cock and cock! but not cockerel.

```
$regex = '/\b';      // The beginning of the regex string syntax
$regex .= implode('\b|\b', $banned_words);      // joins all the banned words to the string with correct regex syntax
$regex .= '\b/i';    // Adds ending to regex syntax. Final i makes it case insensitive
```

Now you can run a single operation on `$result` and get a new string with all the banned words censored. Set your value to be substituted for each banned word

```
$substitute = '****';
```

Then perform the replacement

```
$cleanresult = preg_replace($regex, $substitute, $result);
```

Assuming `$result = 'You are a cock! You prick! You are such a dick.';`

`echo $cleanresult` returns You are a ****! You ****! You are such a ****.

Comment: but we wanted word boundaries your code would match "cock" in "cockerel" which is not what the OP wants

Comment: No it wouldnt. If you read my last sentence I state you have to define your banned words with a space before and after them. If your array looks like this $banned_words = array(' cock ', ' prick '); then it will not match cockerel

Comment: space is not the only word boundary. "you are a cock." it would fail that because the boundary is a full stop. https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: I need the cpu to be used less. Else, page loading takes forever.

Comment: Ah yeah, didn't think about punctuation at the end of a word. Regex it is, I'll edit my answer

Comment: I updated my answer. However if you have limited cpu resources I would be tempted to scrap this approach altogether and just have your proxy insert some javascript code into your page which does the regex search and filtering client side

Comment: I am getting error: "Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 21 in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\codingforum3.php on line 29". I am updating my original post to show my update with miknik's code. It was working fine until I added this line before the cURL: $banned_words = array("Prick","Dick","***");

I even replaced the echo for print_r but same result:
$cleanresult = preg_replace($regex, $substitute, $result);
print_r($cleanresult);

Comment: The code has word wrapped and one of the comments is no longer commented out. Delete this from line 29 "          it case insensitive" It looks like your curl url has word wrapped too, its taking up three lines in my console

Comment: @miknik,

I now see a complete blank page.
I have set error reporting but don't get any.
Do you mind attaching your file and I will donwload it. I use Note Pad++. I have a feeling I am doing something wrong and checking your file and comparing it with mine might do the trick to spot my mistake and solve the issue.

Thanks!

Comment: @miknik,

You mentioned Javascript would be a better solution.
If you know Javascript then care to show a sample ?

Comment: I ran your code and got a blank page. Try taking "***" out of your banned words array, that fixed it for me

Comment: I removed the **** from the array. But no luck. Still blank page.

Comment: Here's my working code, if you copy and paste make sure nothing gets word wrapped, particularly the url as its long. On my server the total page load time is 500ms http://phpfiddle.org/api/raw/0trx-6fng

Comment: miknik is a generous genius! His code from fiddle is working fine! I am not familiar with fiddle though as I am a new student programmer and I came across fiddle earlier few hrs ago when another generous programmer gave me the JS version of this filter which I will now check-out.
@milnik, Is it ok if I share your code by pasting it in all my threads of 10+ forums or do you prefer I link back to your fiddle ? I want other newbies from other forums to benefit from your generosity (code).

Comment: Share it as you wish. If you want to edit and run it from your browser use this link instead http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0trx-6fng

Comment: @miknik, This link shows the full php code that makes-up the Mini Proxy.
https://github.com/joshdick/miniProxy/blob/master/miniProxy.php

On which line should I add your code so that when banned words are found on the proxied pages, then the banned words are substituted ?

On Mini Proxy, I managed to add a url logger. Now, I need to add a words filter.

Comment: Does anyone know on which line in the Mini Proxy I should add miknik's code so that when banned words are found on the proxied pages, then the banned words are substituted ?
Does anyone know on which line in the Mini Proxy I should add miknik's code so that when banned words are found on the proxied pages, then the banned words are substituted ?
Mini Proxy:
https://github.com/joshdick/miniProxy/blob/master/miniProxy.php