# How To Log httpS?

Tags: php, http, https, proxy, referrer

Php Gurus,

I added a url logger to Mini Proxy so that whatever my free users browse gets logged into my db under their account usernames.
The code of Mini Proxy is too long to fit into this post and so you may check it out here:
https://github.com/joshdick/miniProxy/blob/master/miniProxy.php

Using the Mini Proxy, whatever I browse now gets logged into my DB.
Tbl: browsing_history.
Columns: ids, time & dates, usernames, urls.

Now, when I view a url it gets logged.

```
// Dump $url into db

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "INSERT INTO 
browsing_histories(ids,usernames,urls) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'iss', $id, $user, $url);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
if($stmt)
{
    echo "Logged $url to db a success!";
}
else    
{
    echo "Logging $url to db failed!";
}
```

Q1. 
Why is the web proxy php script only fetching "http" but not "https" pages ? Which line to change and to what to fix this ?
I get error:
**Error: The requested URL was disallowed by the server administrator.**

If you check the link for the code then you will see that error is mentioned on line 308 on the script code.

Q2.
I want to fake the REFERRER so the websites (viewed via the proxy) see the referrer as: http://www.example.com/referrer.html and not the actual referrer.
On which line do I add what lines of code to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1: What values you have in `$whitelistPatterns`? [There is url checking](https://github.com/joshdick/miniProxy/blob/master/miniProxy.php#L300-L303) by `preg_match`.

If you don't want to restrict traffic, then remove this security condition.

This may also be due to the fact that you do not have valid root certificates on the server or incorrect time configuration. You can fix it on your server, or ignore this:

```
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

A2: Insert between lines [110-172](https://github.com/joshdick/miniProxy/blob/master/miniProxy.php#L109-L173):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.example.com/1');
```

Any line that isn't in a condition / block will be good. It should not matter. Although `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlRequestHeaders);` set `referer` if this is present in the header. So before this line should be the default referrer and after: overridden. (I don't know if `CURLOPT_REFERER` has a higher priority than`referer` in `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`)

Comment: bato3,

Thank you for your speedy reply. I most appreciate it.
I left the $whitelistPatterns array blank as I am not limiting the proxy to what websites my users can view. I am however, including a content filter:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46555572/finding-banned-words-on-a-page-and-not-within-other-words

Ok. But, which line exactly, you deem is most suitable for me to add the following:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.example.com/1');

Comment: @Muhammad Ali: I improvement answer.

Comment: Why dos the proxy fail to fetch httpS pages ? How to solve this ?
https://github.com/joshdick/miniProxy/blob/master/miniProxy.php

Comment: @MuhammadAli: try disable checking SSL issues: 
          curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
          curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

Comment: I checked the script. But I do not see these 2 lines:

curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

https://github.com/joshdick/miniProxy/blob/master/miniProxy.php

Comment: Insert between lines 110-172:

Comment: bato3, I added your code on line 143:

curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

But, I now get this error:

Notice: Undefined variable: s in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\browser.php on line 134.

Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\browser.php on line 134.

Notice: Undefined variable: s in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\browser.php on line 135.

Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\browser.php on line 135.

Comment: bato3,

I think your code had a typo:

curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

Anyway, another suggested I add the following after "$ch = curl_init(); ":


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

It is now working. The Mini Proxy is now able to view httpS pages. 
Case resolved.

Comment: I don't write this code, just paste it from my library. If all is OK please accept answer.